# Proving a function is primitive recursive using nonatomic functions

Tags: computability, turing-machines

When proving that f is primitive recursive can we use functions that are proven to be primitive recursive like q(x,y)=x/y and other nonaxiomatic functions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. You can begin with functions you know to be primitive recursive and create new primitive recursive functions using primitive recursion and composition. This is part of the definition of “primitive recursive function”.